# C++ `using` keyword vs derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, using-declaration

We have a templated type `Foo<T>`.
In the codebase, it's 99% instantiated with a couple of types, and I would like to use a distinct name for those cases.

What are the pros/cons of the `using` keyword (`using FooA = Foo<A>`) vs declaring an empty derived class (`class FooA : public Foo<A> {};`)

It seems that the derived class is smoother to use (allow forward declaration), but I wonder about any performance (speed or memory) cost.

Comment: An empty derived class is not the same type, as with using. So e.g. you can not bind a reference to Derived to an value of the template type.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a derived class in this situation, unless you need to add additional data members or member functions to `FooA`.

All you are really doing here is creating an alias for a specific instantiation of the `Foo<T>` template. This is exactly what `using` is for, so using `using` makes your intent clear to anyone using type `FooA`.  On the other hand, creating a derived class will add unnecessary complexity and confusion.